# Vertically aligning text in a div using Styled components

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox, styled-components

Having an annoying issue - creating a box to display content - but can't manage to align the text within the Accordion (div) to sit vertically center. The spacing of the chevron is fine (just an icon) - can anyone see where i'm going wrong?

```
const Accordion = styled.div`
  background-color: #e5e9eb;
  height: 56px;
  width: 612px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #27282a;
  margin-bottom: 48px;

  span {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding-left: 24px;
  }
`;

const Chevron = styled.img`
height: 40px;
width: 40px;
float: right;
margin-right: 12px;
`;

const ExpandableString = ({ attribute, className }: Props) => {
  return (
    <Accordion className={className}>4202121100 - More information that can be expanded...
    <Chevron src={chevron} alt="Expand or collapse content" />
      </Accordion>
  );
};
```

Comment: Please create a codesandbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've applied the parent styles to your child (span) div. The container should be flex display and have `align-items: center;`

```
.container (accordion) {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to know what layout you're going for with this code. If you want an accordion with a title and an icon and opens up a panel of text below, here is a high level guide:

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

import Arrow from "../../public/arrow.svg"

// Wraps both title and hidden content
const AccordionWrapper = styled.div`
  align-items: center; // this will vertically center the title text
  background-color: white;
  border-top: ${ props => props.topBorder === true ? "1px solid black" : 'none'};
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  height: auto;
  padding: ${ props => props.padding };
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;

  &:first-child {
    border-top: none;
  }
`;

// Handles inner content and animation
const InternalWrapper = styled.div`
  max-height: ${(props) => props.open ? "auto" : "0"};
  opacity: ${(props) => props.open ? "1" : "0"};
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;
`;

const ArrowButton = styled.img`
  border: none;
  height: min-content;
  margin: none;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transform: ${props => props.open ? "rotate(90deg)" : "rotate(0deg)"}; 
  transform-origin: 40% 40%;
`;

const Title = styled.h2`
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 20px;
`;

/**
 * <Accordion>
 * 
 * Pass in the prop "title" to insert the text that you want to appear next to the arrow button
 * Within the element, pass in the text that you want to appear after the accordion has been activated.
 *
 * @param {obj} children - accordion content should be passed in using the children object 
 * @param {string} padding - how much space do you really want?
 * @param {string} title - pass in the title of the accordion as a prop 
 * @param {boolean} topBorder - do you want that border (true | false)
 *
 */

const Accordion = ({ 
  children, 
  padding = '4vh 0',
  title, 
  topBorder = true
}) => {

  // Set up logic inside of the react component
  // You need to use useRef to give the accordion a waypoint to access
  // Set up a facility to look at the height of your content
  const accordionContent = useRef(null);
  const [accordionHeight, setAccordionHeight] = useState(0)
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  // Get accordion element height on page load
  useEffect( () => {
    setAccordionHeight(accordionContent.current.clientHeight)
  }, [])

  // Toggle accordion state when clicked
  const handleClick = () => {
    setOpen(!open);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <AccordionWrapper 
        onClick={handleClick} 
        open={open}
        padding={padding}
        topBorder={topBorder}>
        <ArrowButton
          alt="Accordion Arrow - click to reveal content"
          open={open}
          src={Arrow}
        />
        <Title>
          {title}
        </Title>
      </AccordionWrapper>
      <InternalWrapper open={open} ref={accordionContent}>
        {children}
      </InternalWrapper>
    </>
  );
};

export default Accordion;
```